# Logstash got exception in running

Tags: logstash

I got this exception in  logstash log when I run it.

> [2018-01-14T15:42:00,912]
>   [ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
>   Unknown setting 'host' for elasticsearch
>       [2018-01-14T15:42:00,921][ERROR][logstash.agent] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/
>       pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", 
>       :message=>"Something is wrong with your configuration.",
>        :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config
>
> /mixin.rb:89:in `config_init
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:63:in`
>   initialize'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:3:in
>   `initialize'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:25:in`
>   initialize'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/plugin_factory.rb:86:in
>   `plugin'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:114:in`
>   plugin'", "(eval):87:in `<eval>'","org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:994:in`
>   eval'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:86:in
>   `initialize'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:171:in`
>   initialize'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in
>   `execute'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:335:in`block
>   in converge_state'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in
>   `with_pipelines'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:332:in`block
>   in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:319:in`
>   converge_state'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in `block
>   in converge_state_and_update'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in`
>   with_pipelines'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in
>   `converge_state_and_update'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in`
>   execute'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:343:in
>   `block in execute'", 
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in`
>   block in initialize'"]}

It is my configure:

```
   input{
 lumberjack {
  port => 5044
  type => "logs"
  ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
 }    
}


filter{
 if[type] == "syslog" {
   grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:sysylog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
     add_field => ["received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ] 
     add_field => ["received_from", "%{host}" ]
   }
   syslog_pri {}
   date {
     match => ["syslog_timestamp", "MMM d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
   }
 }
}

output{
  elasticsearch { host =>localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

How can I solve it . thank you.
I use latest version of ELK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your output elasticsearch plugin, it has host parameter.
It needs a hosts parameter and a string array.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts
My logstash->elastic plugin looks like this:

```
elasticsearch{
  hosts=>["localhost:9200"]
  index=>"logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
```

You might need the index parameter set too.

Comment: You don't need the index parameter. It has a default value: `logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index